# Define the concept of square root (mod n)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers

So i was looking at some of the past papers of my module, the new module has different topics slightly.I was wondering how would you solve this since we didn't cover such topic this year

Define the concept of square root $\pmod{n}$.
Give a non-trivial square root in the $integers$ for $\pmod{143}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give a non-trivial square root for what modulo $143$?  Of $1$? Then one is staring at us in the face, since $12^2=144$.